# Parsing a Stream and a Parameter to a WCF operation contract through JSON

Tags: .net, wcf, stream

I have to call a WCF service to transform an image. Since an image is a stream (can be large) I want to have a method in which I can send a stream as well as couple of parameters (image transformation information) to a method. How can I define the method signature for the operation contract? Note that I am making a JSON call and use an Http post method to send the image. So that I don’t have the luxury of creating a .net proxy.
How can I make a call to the following WCF method? Or is there a better method to do this?
E.g.

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MyOperation", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Public CompositeType1 MyOperation(Stream image,CompositeType2 param){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rajesh answer is incorrect
You can have aditional paramaters whith a Stream

Try this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/{pram1}/{pram2}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string ProcessData(string pram1, string pram2, Stream zipFile);
```

Have a look at this link [WCF UriTemplate and POST data on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/91e1da2d-61f4-44cc-a228-4bd304683bbb)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is when you have Stream as one of the parameter you cannot have additional parameters to that changes your method as follows:

```
[WebInvoke]
public CompositeType1 MyOperation(Stream image)
{}
```

Now in order for you to pass both image and composite type object to that method is achievable but you need to post the request as multipart form data. When you post your request as multipart form data then you would need a parser on the server side that does the parsing of the stream to extract the appropriate content for you i.e. extract the image and your composite type object from the stream. There is already an existing multipart form parser for you to download but you have to customise it to meet your requirements. Which i guess is an complex task. The link for the multipart form parse is [here](http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/38235#458003)

Some information on multipart form data can be found [here](http://antscode.blogspot.com/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html)

I guess the easiest way would be seperate the image upload from the operation and have it seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  code:

```
ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "GET",ResponseFormat=System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle =System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);
        [OperationContract]
        [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);
    }




public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        #region IRestService Members
        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return "You Request Porduct" + ":"+id;

        }
        public string JSONData(string id)
        {
            return "Yor Request Product" +":"+ id;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a small trick. You can take parameter byte[] instead of stream and after that you can convert to stream with this code: 
 `Stream stream = new MemoryStream(yourByteArray);`